# how to retrieve arraylist values into csv file

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, getter

```
`while (sc.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("Inside second while");
                    String data =br.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Scanning");
                    if (index == 0)
                        ud1.setUserId(Integer.parseInt(data));
                    else if (index == 1)
                        ud1.setUserName(data);
                    else if (index == 2)
                        ud1.setUserAddress(data);
                        else if (index == 3){
                        ud1.setUserEmail(data);
                    break;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("invalid data::" + data);
                    }
                    index++;
                }
                index = 0;
                ud.add(ud1);
                System.out.println(ud);`
```

Here i have used setters. Now how should i use getter to retrieve the data of arraylist. Please help me with the for each loop using getters

Comment: Edit the question tags and add the language ;-).

Comment: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have different 'UserData' - Objects in your ArrayList `ud` (It would be helpful to include this and remove less relevant info like the "invalid data" from your code snippet) and you want to write them into a `StringBuilder sb = ...` that will be exported into a CSV-file, you should:

1. Write the CSV Header, if required, in the desired order:

   ```
   sb.append("ID;Name;Address;Email\n");
   ```
2. Iterate over the ArrayList:

   ```
   for(UserData data : ud){
       sb.append(data.getUserID()).append(";");
       // append other entries
       sb.append(data.getUserEmail()).append("\n");
   }
   ```
3. Write the contents of the StringBuilder to a csv-file. Information on writing files can be found here: [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java) or in more detail here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

However, using a `UserData` - object with getters and setters seems to be impractical to be: it would be easier to store the input in an `ArrayList<String>` and iterate them in a nested `for`-loop.